# Jsoup is unable to fetch complete content from a webpage (No errors/exceptions, but misses some content)

Tags: javascript, java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to fetch content from following page with JSOUP:

http://www.exchangeandmart.co.uk/used-cars-for-sale

But it does not fetch the div with id=results, even though it is visible when I open the same link from the browser. Please help me

Java code:

```
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect("http://www.exchangeandmart.co.uk/used-cars-for-sale");
Document doc = connection.get();
System.out.println(doc.getElementById("results")); // prints null
```

**NOTE:** There are no exceptions or errors while downloading the page. Only some of the content in the page is missing. I printed the whole document on console with `System.out.println(doc);` , it was quite different from the page I view in the browser.

Comment: does the `doc.toString()` outputs anything? If no, then the problem relays on establishing connection to the server and downloading the data.

Comment: @SYLARRR I have edited my answer, please have another look.

Comment: Do you happen do you use the JSoup from Android? In this case the mobile web page may be displayed which doesent have elements with id's of `results`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.exchangeandmart.co.uk/used-cars-for-sale").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2").get()`;

Now the page should be rendered as accessed from Chrome on PC.

Comment: Let me check, I am using it on my pc though NOT on android. But lets hope for good.

Comment: Oh goodness me, this worked and worked perfectly. Thanksssssssss a lot thanks thanks

Comment: But I am using it on PC, then why it does not work without doing userAgent stuff

Comment: Reason is simple: when you access the webpage with Jsoup form your PC, the default useragent string is something `APPACHECLIENT 1.4 \ UNKNOWN`. And it looks like the website `http://www.exchangeandmart.co.uk` doesn't know how to handle this kind of user/browser.

Comment: it did not work. please enable javaspcript. BEcause when i go tolink with chrome and go to page source, i cant see all elements but when i click inspect element, i can see anything.