# JSoup and the site I can't scrape

Tags: java, screen-scraping, jsoup

I'm learning to use JSoup and to do so I started with a site which contains football matches. I'm not good at html and this may be the problem, anyhow, I checked the code of the site to understand how to retrieve the information I need. It works fine with the initial page, here's my code:

```
import java.net.URL;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class JSoup_example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL("https://www.bwin.it/sportsbook.aspx"), 1000000);

            Elements resultLinks = doc.select("tr.normal");

            //System.out.println(doc);
            System.out.println(resultLinks.size());

            for (Element link : resultLinks) {
                System.out.println(link.select("td.label").first().text() + " - " + link.select("td.label").last().text());
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm having problems if I try to scrape another page of the same site, for example:

https://www.bwin.it/calcio

which, after checking the code, looks exactly like the first one.
After many attempts I inspected the centra element with my browser (Chrome) and I found that the table which contains the data I want has the attribute "baseURI" set as follow:

https://www.bwin.it/betViewIframe.aspx?SportID=4&bv=bb&selectedLeagues=0

If I put that link in my code it works as expected but I don't understand why it doesn't work with the previous link. So my questions are:

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a better way to retrieve the link of the table insted of doing it manually?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: My best guess is that there is some cookie which states from which url the table data gets populated. When you are making request from JSoup, no cookies are added so the default page is loaded. Also setting your useragent string when doing the request may help. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8133370/797321

Comment: I added the user agent found at http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ but it didn't solve the problem. Maybe the cookie idea is right, I'll try to look into it. Thanks for the tips, I'll keep them in mind for the future.