# Any Javascript prevents my program from crawling this page

Tags: java, javascript, html, web-crawler, jsoup

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.utah.edu/").get();
    Elements lists = doc.select("ul");
    for (Element list: lists) {
        Elements li = list.select("li a");
        if (li.size() > 0) {
            ArrayList<String> anchors = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Element e : li) {
                anchors.add(e.text());
            }
            System.out.println(anchors);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to grab all html lists rendered by the `ul` tag from [this page](http://www.utah.edu/). But it failed. I suspect there's script in the page preventing my program from doing so.

**Edit**: To make my question even simpler, consider the following code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.utah.edu/").get();
Elements lists = doc.select("ul");
System.out.println(lists.size());
```

Output:

```
0
```

Comment: *But it failed.*  What happened exactly?  Is there an error message?  I don't think there's any script that a page can use to prevent you from parsing it.  However, sometimes web servers will block you from downloading the page if you don't include a User Agent in your HTTP request.

Comment: @dbaseman The program ran to an end successfully, but no output was ever sent to the console. Now I'm sure there's no list been extracted by my program.

Comment: @TerryLi jsoup won't execute javascript.

Comment: @xiaoyi ok, what would be the problem this time? I have examined the source code which shows lots of lists are there.

Comment: @TerryLi a few things you may need to check. is `doc.innerHTML()` (not sure the API of jsoup, just get my point) the same as the one you got online? and is `lists` empty or not? etc. You need to perform a debug procedure, to figure out which part goes wrong.

Comment: @xiaoyi I just checked its `innerHTML` finding there's no `ul`s inside. Could those `ul`s I saw from Chrome be generated by scripts on the run?

Comment: @TerryLi A possible answer is that, the User-Agent String sent by jsoup made *utah.edu* think it's a bot instead of a browser. So it returns other page content. You can change your browser's user agent (in chrome's inspector) to jsoup's and see what happens.

Comment: @TerryLi follow this link and have a try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122374/jsoup-is-unable-to-fetch-complete-content-from-a-webpageno-errors-exceptions-b

Comment: @xiaoyi It works! Feel free to add it as an answer if you want so that I can vote for you. You are very helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible answer is that, the *User-Agent* header sent by jsoup made utah.edu think it's a bot instead of a browser. So it returns other page content.

In `org/jsoup/helper/HttpConnection.java` implemented `get()`, which doesn't send *User-Agent* header by default, unless told otherwise.

So you need manually set it by using `userAgent()`.

Example, faking Chrome:

```
String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.utah.edu/").userAgent(ua).get();
```